# Programming bluecore bc417 scr .Uart generates messages when data is fed to the source?

Tags: bluetooth

When programming a Bluecore bc417 chip, does UART generate messages when data is inputted to the source? For example, MESSAGE_MORE_DATA, MESSAGE_MORE_SPACE. For me, for some reason these messages are not generated for UART. They are generated only for rfcomm when I use the SPP profile. If it is possible to change the position, how? If it is possible, then show a little bit of code for the solution.

Comment: yes uart source generates messages (MESSAGE_MORE_DATA and MESSAGE_MORE SPACE). I have only used Bluecore 8675 and 8670 but if the BC417 is based on CSR's XAP then they should work somewhat similarly

Comment: For example if you connect a bluecore chip to the computer through the UART and the computer sends a UART character, it will generate a MESSAGE_MORE_DATA message in the CSR chip

Comment: if you are connecting the chip to PC through UART check the baud rate and hardware control on/off options. It could be a pskey setting issue, search for all the pskeys that have the word "uart" in it. It might give a clue on what to try

Comment: does the CSR baud rate match the PC baud rate? Is hardware flow control turned off in CSR and PC?

Comment: you mean the speed and transmission parameters in the pskey are correct?

Answer (score 2):

Before sending, use the function: MessageSinkTask (Sink,task) In the method main(), before the first message.